# Mouse Pointer Not Showing In Skype Screen Sharing

Tags: skype

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 with the Gnome 3.26.2 desktop. Skype screen sharing works but the mouse pointer does not show. Is there any way to enable this? There are no options in Skype but I wonder if it could be done with some sort of X configuration tweak.

Comment: may be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218176/mouse-pointer-is-not-captured-in-share-screen-mode-ubuntu-18-04-4-lts (which is also unsolved)

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading Skype to the recent version 8.63.0.76.