# Mouse pointer is not captured in 'share screen' mode (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS)

Tags: sharing, mouse-pointer, google-hangouts

When using 'share screen' mode in Google Hangouts Meet, the mouse pointer is not captured. Reports on a similar issue with Skype can be also found in various forums.

Answer (score 1):

Google Meet currently only shows the mouse pointer if you share the "Whole Screen" but not if you only share a Window.